# Underbrace in equation makes expression a bit too big

Tags: underbrace

I have an expression with an `\underbrace`, where the parenthesis and a second partial devirative gets a little to big.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{v_G} =  \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot \left(\frac{1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda}}{1 - \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^2 \underbrace{\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial \lambda^2}}_{=0}} \right) = \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda} \right) 
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
```

and here the result:

[image]

How can I adjust the code so that the second order partial derivative is as big as the term over the fraction line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The simplest would be removing the big parentheses which are redundant. But also the `\underbrace` needs a fix.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply omit those redundant parentheses. And most certainly fix the size of the `\underbrace` object.

It's also possible (but requires a phantom) to have the right size for the parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixedunderbrace}[2]{{\mathpalette\fixed@underbrace{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\fixed@underbrace}[2]{\fixed@@underbrace#1#2}
\newcommand{\fixed@@underbrace}[3]{\underbrace{#1#2}_{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{v_G} =
\frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot 
  \frac{1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda}}
       {1 - \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^2
        \fixedunderbrace{\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial \lambda^2}}{=0}}
= \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot 
  \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda} \right) 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{v_G} =
\frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot 
  \left(
  \frac{1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda}}
       {1 - \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^2
        \smash[b]{\fixedunderbrace{\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial \lambda^2}}{=0}}}
  \right)
  \vphantom{
    \frac{1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda}}
       {1 - \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^2
        \fixedunderbrace{\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial \lambda^2}}{=0}}
  }
= \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot 
  \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda} \right) 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `mathlap` or something like that command is also possible?

Comment: @manooooh No, `\math[r|c|l]lap` is for hiding horizontal lengths; for hiding a vertical length one needs `\smash`; however, the real height has to be reinforced later or the vertical spacing would break (the line below the display would be too near, in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions (the first two of which have already been made by @egreg):

- Omit the large parentheses entirely -- they seem to satisfy no useful purpose.
- Use `\tfrac` (or `\textstyle\frac`) instead of `\frac` in the first argument of `\underbrace`. (By default, the first argument of `\underbrace` is processed in display-style math mode. However, the remainder of the denominator is processed in text style, not display style. That's why it's necessary to write `\tfrac` instead of just `\frac`.)
- Omit all `\cdot` directives. They achieve little but clutter up the appearance of the equation.
- For better horizontal spacing as well as for more typographically-appropriate sizing of the parentheses in the final part of the equation, use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` instead of `\left(` and `\right)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\tfrac" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{1}{v_G} 
= \frac{1}{v_{ph}}  
\frac{1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda}}{%
      1 - \bigl(\frac{\lambda}{n} \bigr)^{\!2} \!
\underbrace{\tfrac{\partial^2 n}{\partial\lambda^2}}_{=0}}
= \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \Bigl( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} 
    \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda} \Bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the `\cfrac` command to have all fractions in display style, or `\tfrac` for the underbraced partial derivative. I don't like such a discrepancy between these two sizes in the same formula, so I suggest using the medium size commands from `nccmath` (~80% of \displaystyle). I give an example of both, with some spacing improvements, and in the second example, the use ofthe `esdiff` package to simpify typing of partial derivatives:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{v_G} = \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot \left(\frac{1 - \cfrac{\lambda}{n\bigstrut[b]} \cfrac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda}}{1 - \biggl(\cfrac{\lambda}{n} \biggr)^{\mkern-5mu 2} \smash[b]{\underbrace{\cfrac{\partial^2 n}{\partial \lambda^2}}_{=0}}} \right) = \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial \lambda} \right)
\end{align*}
\bigskip

\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{v_G} = \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot \left(\frac{1 - \medmath{\frac{\lambda}{n\bigstrut[b]} \diffp{n}{\lambda}}}{1 - \medmath{ \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^{\mkern-5mu 2} \smash[b]{\underbrace{\diffp[2]{n}{\lambda}}_{=0}}}} \right) = \frac{1}{v_{ph}} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n} \diffp{n}{\lambda} \right)
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernhard Thank you very much! Your solution seems to be very compact. In future, I will use the `\usepackage{esdiff}` :)